# Terraform : How to pass output value of one module to another module in azure

Tags: azure, terraform

Environment folder setup:

- Module A contains `rg.tf` file to create resource group on azure.
- Module B contains `vnet.tf` file and it needs resource group name from Module A.

How do i use the output of one into another ?

`Terraform -v = Terraform v0.12.6`

Folder Struture :

```
C:\Terraform\ResourceGroup
   \rg.tf 
   \var.tf
   \output.tf
C:\Terraform\Vnet
    \vnet.tf
```

`rg.tf` contains:

```
provider "azurerm" { 
  Subscription ID : xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  Subscription Name :xxxxxxxxxxxxx
  Client ID : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  Client Secret: xxxxxxxxxxxx
}
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    storage_account_name  = xxxxxxxxxxxxx
    resource_group_name   = xxxxxxxxxxxxx
    container_name        = "versiontf"
    key                   = "terraform.tfstate"
  }
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "res_group" {
  location = "${var.location}"
  name     = "${var.name}"
}
```

`var.tf` contains

```
variable "location" {
  default     = "West US"
}

variable "name" {
  default = "testing"
}
```

`output.tf` contains:

```
output "rg_name" {
  value = "${azurerm_resource_group.res_group.name}"
}
```

`vnet.tf` contains:

```
provider "azurerm" { 
  Subscription ID : xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  Subscription Name :xxxxxxxxxxxxx
  Client ID : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  Client Secret: xxxxxxxxxxxx
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "test" {
  name                = "vnet"
  location            = "east us"
  resource_group_name = "????????????"  (How do i read the resource group name which i created using rg.tf)
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}
```

FYI: I am able to create and add output values to the backend state file.

Comment: Can you share your Terraform code? Also include the directory layout of things if  they are in separate files.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR  i have added the folder structure and the entire code. Thank you.

Comment: I tried the below code but it shows following error i posted. I tried changing the name and location and playing around it also. Able to create the RG but while creating vnet the erros is thrown.

Comment: Can you show the message of the error? It works well on my side.

Comment: on ..\rg\main.tf line 8, in resource "azurerm_resource_group"  "rgtest":  8: resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rgtest" {

Comment: @CharlesXu It works for me. I am able to pass the input of one module into another by using data source. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use the module in the file `vnet.tf` like below:

```
provider "azurerm" { 
    Subscription ID : xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    Subscription Name :xxxxxxxxxxxxx
    Client ID : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    Client Secret: xxxxxxxxxxxx
}

module "resourceGroup" {
  source = "../ResourceGroup"

  # the variable that you set for your resource group
  name = "rg_name"
  location = "rg_location"

}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "test" {
    name                = "vnet"
    location            = "east us"

    # use the module resource group
    resource_group_name = "${module.resourceGroup.rg_name}"     

    address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}
```